# How to write an Soql query to fetch all the contact which has opportunites only in stage "closed won"

Tags: apex, soql, query, force.com

I am writing a logic where i need all the contact which has all the opportunities in closed won stage.

I.e If we have an contact which has 2 opportunity, one is closed won and other is prospect then this contact should not be present in query result.

if a contact has only 2 opportunities and if both are in closed won stage then that contact should appear in result.

Comment: Do you have any Custom relationship field on Opportunity pointing to Contact? Or standard Account relationship is in a picture?

Comment: I have a custom relationship on opportunity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below query will help you to filter the Contact on the basis of your requirement.

```
SELECT Id, LastName, (SELECT Id, Name FROM Opportunities__r WHERE StageName = 'Closed Won') FROM Contact Where ID Not IN (SELECT Contact__c FROM Opportunity WHERE StageName != 'Closed Won')
```

However, this query will return all the Contacts including Contacts with no Opportunities as well. If you are only looking for Contact having at least a single Opportunity then do check the **contact.Opportunities__r.size()** before processing further logic.

**Note:** Ensure you are having the same relationship names.

Answer (score 0):

should be something like this

```
select Id,(select Id,Name from opportunities where stage != 'Closed Won') from Contact
```